# Как сделать ввод в переменную на node.JS?

Tags: javascript, python, input

Всем привет! Как сделать ввод в переменную, предлагаю пример в Python:

```
a = input();
print(a);
```

Можно ли так сделать в JS?

Comment: Для браузера или для nodejs?

Comment: @SwaD для  node.js